AccountNotFound when fetching an address with transactions
I have a bot that finds new pairs on raydium pool.
When it finds the innitialize pool transaction, it fetches poolInfo. All is being done within milliseconds. But, when it comes to fetch base_vault and quote_vault addresses from pool info for token account balance, I get error AccountNotFound.
If I wait for 10 seconds and try again, it fetches all the data like it should. Problem is, theres a delay of like 10 seconds between the first transactions on those addresses and my bot reacting to them (tells me address not found but theres already transactions on the address so that should be found).
My code seems to be fine. My rpc node is preety fast, like I said all is being done withing milliseconds, all except this part:
loop {
    match client.get_account(&pool_info_unwrapped.base_vault).await {
        Ok(_) => {
            match client.get_account(&pool_info_unwrapped.quote_vault).await {
                Ok(_) => {
                    break;
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    error!("Failed to get quote vault account data: {}. Retrying in 500ms...", e);
                    tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
                }
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Failed to get base vault account data: {}. Retrying in 500ms...", e);
            tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
        }
    }
}

Like you see, I implemented a cycle to try again. What could be the cause of that 10+ seconds delay? Maybe im doing something wrong?

Maybe an issue with transaction confirmation? https://solana.com/docs/advanced/confirmation
